# Spark-MultiNode-Clustering

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have deployed the spark cluster and submit the spark processing using yarn resource manager. My cluster is working fine with hdfs (hadoop) setting, but facing problem regarding spark staging when I run the spark-submit, below the screen of errors where I am stuck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1lk8.png)

From where spark execute this jar file, I also add the jar in spark  jars directory.

Comment: Your application needs commons-io bundled as part of its own JAR. Don't copy dependency JARs around on the cluster

Comment: In spark jar directory there are so many common-io jars  exist but it could not pick form there why ?

Comment: I'm not talking about any Spark directory. You need to create an "uber jar" for your own application

Comment: It's really helpful when the error message is typed into the question instead of a screen shot.  You might get more answers if the error message base built into the question.